# Filter WP_Query for posts having a certain meta-value

Tags: custom-field, filters, wp-query

How to filter WP_Query for posts having a certain meta-value, without using a Custom Select Query?

I have a custom posttype with meta-key: "open", and meta-value options: "yes" or "no".

I would like to show posts only with meta_value = yes, for meta_key = "open".

```
function filter_where($where = '') {    

    $open = "yes";

    //$where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-2 days')) . "'";
    return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
```

Comment: Are you doing this in a template file? Can you post the full code of your template file then? Is this the main loop of this page?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am not sure from your wording if you hadn't tried it with query argument or it didn't work?

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array( 'meta_key' => 'open', 'meta_value' => 'yes' ));
```

[Custom Field Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) in Codex.

Comment: thanks for your swift reply. I did try that, but for some reason it does not work for me. For, it throws a 404.

Comment: Where did you place the code?

Comment: I put it in a $args array after my $paged setting: $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; and before: $temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null; $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

Comment: @Henk Jan please add code to your question, comment are unsuitable for it

Comment: my custom post type was not registered properly in the database. After I fixed that, your solution did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $querystr = "
    SELECT wposts.* 
    FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
    WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id 
    AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'custom-key' 
    AND wposts.post_type = 'page' 
    ORDER BY wpostmeta.meta_value DESC
    ";
```

Comment: An explanation would tell us why this is an answer.

Comment: Double that. Also: Use the `$wpdb` methods when doing queries.

Comment: You definitely want to use WP_Query not raw SQL. Why? Caches, multisite, you name it.